# URL and page refresh issue for Multilingual site on Django

Tags: python, html, django

plz help me to solve one issue. I have a Multilingual site on Django with standart internationalization framework.

Settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'
     ...]

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ja', _('Japanese')),
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LOCALE_PATHS = ['../locale/']
```

All *.mo and *.po files for both languages are successfully created.

main.html has a code snippet for language switching:

```
{% get_current_language as CURRENT_LANGUAGE %}
{% get_available_languages as AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES as languages %}
<div class="languages">
   <p>{% trans "Language" %}:</p>
   <ul class="languages">
        {% for language in languages %}
           <li>
              <a href="/{{ language.code }}/"
                 {% if language.code == CURRENT_LANGUAGE %} class="active"{% endif %}>
                 {{ language.name_local }}
              </a>
           </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
        path('', include('mysite.urls'))
)
```

simplified website structure

```
main.html
--page1.html
--page2.html
```

Now I can click and change the page translation, but I've faced with next issue. When I switch the language, e.g. from main/en/page1 I redirected back to the main/ja page, regardless my current location on a website structure. In other words, **I'd like to stay at the same page1 when I switch the language and change only the language prefix main/en/page1 -> main/ja/page1.** The best working example is [DjangoDocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) witch has the language switcher on the bottom-right position and works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue.
Just add line {{ request.get_full_path |slice:'4:'}} to the <a href=> part.

```
{% get_available_languages as AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES as languages %}
<div class="languages">
   <p>{% trans "Language" %}:</p>
   <ul class="languages">
        {% for language in languages %}
           <li>
              <a href="/{{ language.code }}/ {{ request.get_full_path |slice:'4:'}}"
                 {% if language.code == CURRENT_LANGUAGE %} class="active"{% endif %}>
                 {{ language.name_local }}
              </a>
           </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```